Receving an error when trying to add a column
I've tried to add a column in my dataset but I receive an error when running the following snippet:
M = ADDCOLUMNS(table, "RAN", RAND())

The error, translated to English, is

Measure report table[M] contain syntax error at row 1, pos 1.
The expression refers to more columns. It is not possible convert more columns in a scalar value.

How can I solve this error and add the column?

It looks like you want to create a column with random number
pls try this
=Number.RandomBetween(0,1)


or use DAX
Column = RAND()


The problem is add the column
